# Definition of graphics needed

Tags: graphics

It is not isometric, neither is it pure 2D.  What is this graphics view called?

[image]

Comment: Pixelated Graphics

Comment: These are visible graphics.

Comment: Vipar, I'm not talking about the graphic style itself (should have made it clearer) but this strange point of view.  Not iso projection but rather above and tilted?

Comment: Does it need a name? If you're trying to simulate it, just try. Having a name for it won't help you there.

Comment: A name would help with locating similar graphical content and possible rendering techniques.

Comment: @user357320: That might be true if game developers/gamers were at all consistent about how they name *anything*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Or how they searched for it: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12764/what-graphic-is-final-fantasy-6-chrono-trigger-alundra-etc

Answer (score 1):

If you don't consider it as simply *perspective* (ie if the view is actually *orthographic*) then it would be called an [oblique projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection). [See this discussion on Ultima 7's perspective/projection](http://opengameart.org/forumtopic/reverse-engineering-ultima-vii-isometrics-wip).

Comment: Perhaps adding "overhead" oblique projection would elaborate the view.  A mathematical term is affine transformation, in which parallel lines are preserved, as opposed to projective transformation (where parallels meet at points on the horizon).

Comment: An orthographic projection has parallel lines that meet at +/-infinity